# Capturing python windowed output from C++ embedded interpreter

Tags: python, c++, matplotlib, boost-python, pybind11

I am using boost python to embed a python interpreter in a C++ application.
(pybind11 would also be fine)

If I call matplotlib from the embedded interpreter with something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,4,9,16])
plt.show()
```

The python interpreter opens a new window (separate from my application's primary window) to display the matplotlib plot.

I know it's a long shot, but is there any way to intercept this?
I would like to be able to capture the pixels displayed in this separate window and display them within the graphics context of my application's primary window.

I'm guessing this is not possible due to how I believe the window is being generated.
But wanted to check if anyone might have any insights on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of one of the [hardcopy backends](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) of matplotlib and save the pixels of the canvas to a string which can be [exported to your C++ context](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/advanced/embedding.html#executing-python-code). Below are the python codes:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot

fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot ( 111 )

ax.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,4,9,16])

fig.canvas.draw ()

w,h = fig.canvas.get_width_height()  # width and height of the canvas
buf = fig.canvas.tostring_argb()     # a byte string of type uint8
```

In your C++ code you can use variables `w`, `h` and `buf` to display the figure in your primary window.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. 
I assume there's no way to intercept agnostically (without changes to the python code)?

Comment: You can translate the python code into the corresponding C++ code if that's what you mean. For example, `py::object matplotlib = py::module::import("matplotlib ");
py::object mpluse= matplotlib.attr("use");mpluse("Agg");` ... (using pybind11)

Comment: Thanks. The python user would still need to call "buf = fig.canvas.tostring_argb()". But seems like there's no way around that.